# How to post form array list into the web api?

Tags: angular, typescript, entity-framework, formarray

I need to post Form array as a whole without looping in the angular typescript. How can I post form array without looping?

```
 for(const item of this.Form.value?.IssuanceArray) {
           this.microSvc.postDetails(item).subscribe((response) => {
 }) }
```

```
postDetails(data: any): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post<any>(this.appsettings.baseURL + 'ItemPost/TransactionDetailsNoLoop', data)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
  }
```

```
   [HttpPost("TransactionDetailsNoLoop")]
        public Task<ActionResult<TRANSACTIONDETAILS>> AddTransactionDetailsOne([FromBody] List<TransactionDetailsDTO> transactionDetailsDTO)
        {

            return null;
        }
```

In this example: I want to try posting form array with loop but in my case, I need to post form array without using for loop. Can someone please help me with my case.

Comment: Since your API action expects to receive an array from the request body, you don't need the loop. Just directly post the array from the form array to the API.

Comment: How can I directly post the form array to the API using the code written above? @YongShun

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you are passing the `IssuanceArray` to API action, you don't need the loop to send requests for each item to the API. As mentioned in the comment, your API action expects an array from the request body, so straight send the request with the array in the request body.

```js
this.microSvc.postDetails(this.Form.value?.IssuanceArray).subscribe((response) => {

})
```

```js
postDetails(data: any[]): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.post<any>(this.appsettings.baseURL + 'ItemPost/TransactionDetailsNoLoop', data)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
}
```